# Having duplicate entry error with Panelizer module

Tags: 7, panels

I installed the [Panelizer](http://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) module and enabled it for a specific content type. When trying to add new content, I get a duplicate entry error as follows :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'node-196-197-page_manager' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT
>   INTO {panelizer_entity} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id,
>   no_blocks, css_id, pipeline, did, view_mode, css_class, title_element,
>   link_to_entity) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 196
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 197 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => standard
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =>
>   page_manager [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => [:db_insert_placeholder_9]
>   => H2 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 1 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 6888 of
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/jkl/includes/common.inc).

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known bug:  [unable to edit nodes with default panelizer state.](http://drupal.org/node/1412022)

Try the patches in the above issue.  Looks like it might be useful to chip in there with your issue also!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chapabu. I've been through those, and tried merlinofchaos's #7 patch and get this in my apache error log : Fatal error: Declaration of PanelizerEntityNode::get_default_display() must be compatible with that of PanelizerEntityInterface::get_default_display() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/jkl/sites/all/modules/contrib/panelizer/plugins‌​/entity/PanelizerEntityNode.class.php on line 12 The other patches there don't work at all. :/